# Using Symfony's Form Event to remove some of the data sent to a form

Tags: forms, symfony

I have checkboxes and I want to find out the items with checked checkboxes and send only them to the database. So I made this:

```
class NotNeededFieldsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_BIND => 'preBindData');
    }

    public function preBindData(FormEvent $event)
    {    
        $data = $event->getData();

        $count = count($data['items']);

        for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++){
             if (!array_key_exists('enabled', $data['items'][$i])){   
                unset($data['items'][$i]);               
             } 
        }       

        $event->setData($data);

    }
}
```

When I test to see $event->getData has exactly what I want.

In controller:

```
 $form = $this->formFactory->create(new ItemType(), $item);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);           
                if ($form->isValid()) {  

                    $this->em->persist($item);
                    $this->em->flush();
                }
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->router->generate('home'));
```

The problem is that still checked and unchecked items are in the database :(

Any ideas why and how to fix this? Thanks very much in advance! :)

Comment: Have you bound the event within ItemType itself? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-subscriber-to-a-form-class

Comment: Yes, I have :( It works, the data array is correct, but when I check in the controller the `$item` still has all the data.

Comment: ah, are you editing a record? By un-setting the data as by removing it you aren't overriding it. E.g. Try replacing the unset, with $data['items'][$i] = 0;

Comment: It's the same again - the result is not given to the request object :(
I tried replacing the body of the function preBindData with this

`$event->setData('a'); echo('yes');` and the result is - the content of the form is not changed, but yes is echoed.

Comment: checkout the different Form Events in the class itself : https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/FormEvents.php?source=cc perhaps PRE_SET_DATA might be better since that is passing directly to the entity?

Comment: @Faery which Symfony version?

Comment: @gilden The version is 2.2.4

Comment: @Faery please read this if you are using doctrine http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal

Answer (score 0):

As checkbox is in fact a collection, maybe you should refer to this part of the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-tags-to-be-removed

Specially the "Doctrine: Ensuring the database persistence" part.
You have to manually remove the enities still stored in the database but not in the form anymore

```
        // filter $originalTags to contain tags no longer present
    foreach ($task->getTags() as $tag) {
        foreach ($originalTags as $key => $toDel) {
            if ($toDel->getId() === $tag->getId()) {
                unset($originalTags[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    // remove the relationship between the tag and the Task
    foreach ($originalTags as $tag) {
        // remove the Task from the Tag
        $tag->getTasks()->removeElement($task);

        // if it were a ManyToOne relationship, remove the relationship like this
        // $tag->setTask(null);

        $em->persist($tag);

        // if you wanted to delete the Tag entirely, you can also do that
        // $em->remove($tag);
    }
```